# Dangers of having MRI, CT-scan, & X-ray within a seven day period?

Tags: risks, mri, x-rays, ct-scans, bioelectromagnetics

I had a MRI last week for my spine. I got a call today that I'm having a CT-scan tomorrow for my abdomen (unrelated issue). The day after tomorrow, I'm having X-rays done on my teeth at the dentist because I cracked my teeth. These are all unrelated medical issues. But all these medical issues required medical-imaging that happened to be scheduled within 7 days of each other.

**Is it dangerous to have a MRI, CT-scan, and an X-ray all within a week's period?** Are they all radioactive? Also, I had an ultrasound 2 weeks ago (which was unhelpful --- which is why I'm now having the CT-scan).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The amounts of radiation in today's machines is low enough that there is no negative impact to be expected.

For comparison:

**X-Rays**: A chest X-ray gives you about 10 mrem

**MRI**s measure the reaction time of molecules (in the body) to changes of outside magnetic fields. No radiation or radioactivity is involved at all.

**CT-Scans**:
A chest CT scan clocks in at about 200mrem.

**Natural background radiation** is around 300 mrem.

**Smoking** five cigarettes a day means you *inhale* about 1300 mrem a year.

See this list for many more examples:http://www.iem-inc.com/information/tools/common-radiation-exposures